# Is there a way to send connection requests to local devices through an app?

Tags: react-native, bluetooth, expo, wifi-direct

What I'm visualizing:

4 different devices each running the same app while connected to the Internet via their cellular networks. Is there a way I can broadcast connection requests to all these devices, considering that they're not on the same local network?

I don't have any solid ideas on how to achieve this, maybe something in the the Bluetooth/Wi-Fi Direct (PAN) space?

Comment: What do you expect to happen after you send your connection requests?

Comment: They establish a P2P network, with the device sending the requests acting as the hub? Sorry, my vocabulary has disappeared after covid.

Comment: Ah I see, thanks for clarifying. Couldn't you do it without sending the request over the Internet? If every app is the same let them search (and connect) to one specific device that currently does not exist. If you select one device to be the host just let it appear to be the specific device and all other devices should automatically connect to it. This would cause some battery drainage because you are always searching for the device, but after that works you could still implement your Internet solution (and turn on the Bluetooth search only on command)